# force schema generation with nest - typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

what is the equivalent of `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` with nest and typeorm ?

During the developpment, I don't want to generate migrations files, I want to force the update of the database schema

I'm getting this error in console

`QueryFailedError: column "email" of relation "supplier" contains null values`

## Edit

I deleted the data in my db, and the schema did upgrade.

But how to force clean the database ?

I found :

`typeorm schema:drop -- -d path-to-datasource-config`

but what is the path to datasource in nest case ?